# Check if each item in an array is identical in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to test whether each item in an array is identical to each other. For example:

```
var list = ["l","r","b"]
```

Should evaluate as `false`, because each item is not identical. On the other hand this:

```
var list = ["b", "b", "b"]
```

Should evaluate as `true` because they are all identical. What would be the most efficient (in speed/resources) way of achieving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all values of array are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832603/check-if-all-values-of-array-are-equal)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function identical(array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if(array[i] !== array[i+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I opted for this solution, thanks. Pimvdb had a very elegant solution with array.every but that would of required adding a big chunk of code (for non-ES5 compliant browser support) to an already large document for just one instance of .every so I opted for this instead.

Comment: Your solution made the most sense to me. However, I'd change the "!=" to "!==" because your solution returns true in the following array [1,1,1,1,1,1,"1"] where the last character is a string.

Comment: I'd like to see something similar but for objects.

Comment: Nice solution in traditional way. ES5 introduced Array.every(), which could be used for one linear solution as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646943/check-if-each-item-in-an-array-is-identical-in-javascript/54826946#54826946

Answer (score 19):

In ES5, you could do:

```
arr.every(function(v, i, a) {
   // first item: nothing to compare with (and, single element arrays should return true)
   // otherwise:  compare current value to previous value
   return i === 0 || v === a[i - 1];
});
```

`.every` does short-circuit as well.

Comment: Nice, didn't know this existed and going to start using this myself.  Just adding a pointer to the docs for array.every https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: Thanks, that's a very elegant solution. I went for Dogberts solution in the end to avoid adding the array.every code to support older browsers - but in principle this would have worked nicely.

Comment: Here no need to compare each predecessor with the current value i.e. v===a[i-1].
Anyways a you can find one linear solution at:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54826946/8958729

Answer (score 12):

You could always do a new Set, and check the length.

```
var set1 = [...new Set(list)].length === 1;
```

Answer (score 9):

The one line answer is:

```
arr.every((val, ind, arr) => val === arr[0]);
```

You can look into [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for more details.

**Note:**

1. [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is available `ES5` onwards.
2. This method returns `true` for any condition put on an empty array.
3. Syntax: `arr.every(callback[, thisArg])`  or  `array.every(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)`
4. It does not change the original array
5. The execution of every() is [short-circuited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). As soon as [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) finds an array element that doesn't match the predicate, it immediately returns false and doesn't iterate over the remaining elements

Comment: i think `.some` with `!=` would also work

Answer (score 4):

```
arr.every(i=>i==arr[0]) //will return true if all items in arr are identical
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function matchList(list) {
  var listItem = list[0];

  for (index in list) {
    if(list[index] != listItem {
       return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: it will fail at the last element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = ["b", "b", "b"];
var checkItem = list[0];
var isSame = true;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if (list[i] != checkItem) {
    isSame = false;
    break;
  }
}
return isSame;
```

Comment: Just return false when you first encounter it.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if the OP wanted it for use later, or returned in a function.

Comment: You can use every() for one linear solution. 
Ref:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54826946/8958729

Answer (score 1):

```js
function identical(array) {
  // a variable holding standard value
  //against this standard value we are examining the array
  var standard = array[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== standard) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

identical([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]); //return true
identical(['a', 'a', 'a']); //return true
identical(['a', 'a', 'b'])
```

```js
function identical(array) {
  // a variable holding standard value
  //against this standard value we are examining the array
  var standard = array[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== standard) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

identical([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]); //return true
identical(['a', 'a', 'a']); //return true
identical(['a', 'a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to remove duplicates (check out [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)), and then check to see if the length == 1. That would mean that all items were the same.

Comment: That would be O(n^2) (or O(n log n) depending on the sorting algorithm). Too slow.

Comment: I was actually suggesting the second answer (should have specified), that remove duplicates without sorting.

Answer (score 0):

```
function allEqual(list)
{
    if(list.length == 0 || list.length == 1)
    {
      return true;
    }

    for (index in list) {
    if(list[index] != list[index+1] {
       return false;
    }
  }

  return true;

}
```

Comment: Like my first answer: it will fail at the last element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

To check if all values in an array are equal in JavaScript, you can use the every() method in combination with the === operator to compare each element of the array to the first element, like this:

```
function allEqual(arr) {
  return arr.every(val => val === arr[0]);
}
```

This function takes an array arr as its parameter and returns true if all values in the array are equal, and false otherwise.

Here's an example usage:

```
const arr1 = [1, 1, 1, 1];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const arr3 = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'];

console.log(allEqual(arr1)); // true
console.log(allEqual(arr2)); // false
console.log(allEqual(arr3)); // true
```

In the example above, arr1 and arr3 contain only equal values, so the allEqual() function returns true for both of them. arr2 contains different values, so the function returns false.