# Check if all values of array are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find arrays where all values are equal. What's the fastest way to do this? Should I loop through it and just compare values?

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'] // true
['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'] // false
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I bet you are already thinking about the best solution ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Not to mention the willingness of askers to actually accept answers. Users with 1 rep often seem to be ask & run types that leave as soon as they have a copy-paste-able answer, lately.

Comment: Very right things you say here. But stackoverflow is very vulnerable to easy to ask questions. Just check out the top votes page.

Comment: Something around this approach should work ? `a.join(',').split(a[0]).length === a.length + 1`

Comment: @Jashwant: Very clever! Although that'll only work with strings, or if you don't mind `1` to equal `'1'`. I'd upvote it if it were an answer, though ;-)

Comment: I upvoted the comment at least. This is almost as awesome as that `JSON.stringify` comparison solution someone has posted (and deleted) here.

Comment: Both arrays of OP has strings only. I was thinking that there's much easier approach. Let me put this as answer. Someone else can make it better.

Comment: This is a bit out of topic, but wrom what words the "OP" shortcut consists? I know it means answer, but I don't understand...

Comment: @TomášZato: "OP" means "original poster" (the person asking the question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if each item in an array is identical in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646943/check-if-each-item-in-an-array-is-identical-in-javascript)

Comment: First of all, this is an exact dupe. Second, the `Array#every` answer in original question (the best answer for current state of browsers) is already there, then here we see all kinds of crazy solutions except for golopot's. What the heel is going on here?!!

Comment: I fancy `JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2) `

Answer (score 550, accepted):

```
const allEqual = arr => arr.every( v => v === arr[0] )
allEqual( [1,1,1,1] )  // true
```

Or one-liner:

```
[1,1,1,1].every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] )   // true
```

[Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (from MDN) :
    The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Comment: Brevity is the soul of wit

Comment: `const everythings_equal = array => array.every(thing => thing === array[0]);`

Comment: @Jan `every` does early return as well.

Comment: IE don't support this. :(

Comment: Note: This solution will return true if the array is empty, too!

Comment: @MaximZubarev well, all elements *are* equal in that case.

Comment: @Jan: as mentioned by golopot, your proposal with `some` doesn't bring any speed advantage. From the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) : "If such an element is found, the every method immediately returns false.". And the output of your code should also be negated in order to return the same value as `allEqual`. `arr = [1, 1, 1, 1]; arr.some( v => v !== arr[0] )` returns `false`. I just hope your comment didn't lead 24 people to write buggy code.

Comment: How would you write this without the arrow syntax?

Comment: why do all the answers say == arr[0] instead of == arr[index]?

Comment: @quemeful Why would `index` be used? If all elements are equal, then they must all equal the first element.

Comment: ah I misunderstood the question, I thought it was trying to find two arrays that are equal, not an array where all elements are equal

Comment: @EricDuminil: I deleted my comment, so no one else can copy-paste my mistake anymore :D

Answer (score 115):

**Edit:** Be a Red ninja:

```
!!array.reduce(function(a, b){ return (a === b) ? a : NaN; });
```

Results:

```
var array = ["a", "a", "a"] => result: "true"
var array = ["a", "b", "a"] => result: "false"
var array = ["false", ""] => result: "false"
var array = ["false", false] => result: "false"
var array = ["false", "false"] => result: "true"
var array = [NaN, NaN] => result: "false"
```

---

Warning:

```
var array = [] => result: TypeError thrown
```

This is because we do not pass an *initialValue*. So, you may wish to check `array.length` first.

Comment: +1 I tried to come up with a `reduce` version of this myself but didn't succeed. This is pretty cool.

Comment: might be a bit late to the party... i think this doesn't work if your array is made of `false`s!
for example try [false, false, false].reduce(function(a, b){return (a === b)?a:false;});

Comment: Small change: arr.reduce(function(a, b){return (a === b)?a:false;}) === arr[0];

Comment: @Martin This won't work either... check with [false, false, true] array (will return true)

Comment: @Martin: `["false", ""]` returns `true` :/

Comment: This can be taken up a notch by using `NaN`. Since both `NaN === NaN` and `NaN !== NaN` are false, it guarantees that once the `prev` is set to NaN then no value can take it out. Also adding in a double negation converts the results to `true` and `false`, since `NaN` is falsy. Final form: `!!array.reduce(function(a, b){ return (a === b) ? a : NaN; });`

Comment: Very good indeed. Original code updated to use NaN instead of false.

Comment: Nice solution, though it means that the entire array is always checked, even when only the beginning is required.

Comment: `[null, null]` evals to `false`. How about using `Symbol()` which is guaranteed to be different from any other value and then do a: `arr[0]===arr.reduce( function(accum,curr) { if (accum===curr) return curr; else return Symbol(); } )`

Comment: like said before, `[null, null]` evals to `false`. Personally I don't like the `new Symbol()` approach. What about this:
```const a = [null, null];
a[0] === a.reduce((a,b) => _.isEqual(a,b) ? a : NaN);
// => true
```

Comment: **DOWNVOTED**. What if the elements are equal but **_falsy_**?

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't work with booleans values.

Comment: It is so easy to break it with the following input: `[false, false]`, `[0, 0]`, `[null, null]` and so on. If you must use reduce, pass an object containing previous value and a cumulative result.

Comment: The easiest way to use `.reduce` here is to just compare each element with the first element and keep ANDing with the previous results `arr.reduce((res, el, i, arr) => res && el === arr[i], true)` no need to throw in random other values. However, that's still basically re-doing an `every`, so why bother?

Answer (score 75):

You can turn the Array into a Set. If the size of the Set is equal to 1, then all elements of the Array are equal.

```
function allEqual(arr) {
  return new Set(arr).size == 1;
}

allEqual(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']); // true
allEqual(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']); // false
```

Comment: **Brilliant.** Just note that `allEqual([NaN, NaN])` gives `true` in this case.

Comment: ^ because both `NaN === NaN` and `NaN == NaN` evaluate to `false`

Comment: should use `===` for a strict comparison

Comment: This solution feels "pythonic", cheers!

Comment: You need to know, that this answer is much more slower than accepted (about 75% slower on Apple M1, Chrome 109). So you shouldn't use this variant with big arrays.

Answer (score 64):

This works. You create a method on Array by using prototype.

```js
if (Array.prototype.allValuesSame === undefined) {
  Array.prototype.allValuesSame = function() {
    for (let i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i] !== this[0]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Call this in this way:

```js
let a = ['a', 'a', 'a'];
let b = a.allValuesSame(); // true
a = ['a', 'b', 'a'];
b = a.allValuesSame();     // false
```

Comment: very nice, but beware: IE does not support this way of assigning prototypes. I use it anyway.

Comment: You don't need the `else` block in there, because the `if` will return a value from the function, before the code below it has a chance to be executed, if the condition in the `if` is `true`. If it's `false`, the `else` should be executed any way, no need to wrap it in extra `{}`'s

Comment: @TomášZato: IE supports augmenting the `Array.prototype` just fine (even IE6). It's only DOM element prototypes that some older versions of IE don't support augmenting.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Ah, thank you and sorry for my missinformation.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to be monkey patching built-in prototypes. If multiple libraries do it, it can lead to unexpected behavior that's very difficult to debug.

Comment: @MarkWilbur So build it as a global function `function allValuesSame(arr)`

Comment: @MarkWilbur +1 especially if you do a for..in loop on next arrays, you'll get `allValuesSame` in the loop

Comment: I went ahead and modernized this, without altering the intent.

Answer (score 33):

In JavaScript 1.6, you can use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
function AllTheSame(array) {
    var first = array[0];
    return array.every(function(element) {
        return element === first;
    });
}
```

You probably need some sanity checks, e.g. when the array has no elements. (Also, this won't work when all elements are `NaN` since `NaN !== NaN`, but that shouldn't be an issue... right?)

Answer (score 17):

And for performance comparison I also did a benchmark:

```
function allAreEqual(array){
    if(!array.length) return true;
    // I also made sure it works with [false, false] array
    return array.reduce(function(a, b){return (a === b)?a:(!b);}) === array[0];
}
function same(a) {
    if (!a.length) return true;
    return !a.filter(function (e) {
        return e !== a[0];
    }).length;
}

function allTheSame(array) {
    var first = array[0];
    return array.every(function(element) {
        return element === first;
    });
}

function useSome(array){
    return !array.some(function(value, index, array){
        return value !== array[0];
    });
}
```

Results:

```
allAreEqual x 47,565 ops/sec ±0.16% (100 runs sampled)
same x 42,529 ops/sec ±1.74% (92 runs sampled)
allTheSame x 66,437 ops/sec ±0.45% (102 runs sampled)
useSome x 70,102 ops/sec ±0.27% (100 runs sampled)
```

So apparently using builtin array.some() is the fastest method of the ones sampled.

Comment: Good idea to check what's more performant here. The reason why `Array#some` is going to sometimes outperform is that once the callback function returns true, it stops iterating. So, if all the elements are in fact equal, the performance should be identical to `Array#every`. And the relative performance when all elements are not equal will vary based on the index of the first non-matching element.

Comment: Nice one. You could have named each with the function used lol. E.g.: reduce, filter, every, some

Comment: where s the native for loop, I bet that outperforms all of these by a factor of 5

Comment: @Martin - where do you usually run performance checks?

Answer (score 14):

update 2022 version: use `Set()`

```js
     let a = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'];
     let b = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];
     const check = (list) => {
        const setItem = new Set(list);
        return setItem.size <= 1;
     }

     const checkShort = (list) => (new Set(list)).size <= 1        
     
      check(a); // false;
      check(b); // true;
      checkShort(a); // false
      checkShort(b); // true
```

Update new solution: check index

```
 let a = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'];
 let b = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];
 let check = (list) => list.every(item => list.indexOf(item) === 0);
 check(a); // false;
 check(b); // true;
```

Updated with ES6:
Use `list.every` is the fastest way:

```
 let a = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'];
 let check = (list) => list.every(item => item === list[0]);
```

old version:

```
      var listTrue = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];
      var listFalse = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'ab'];

      function areWeTheSame(list) { 
         var sample = list[0];
         return (list.every((item) => item === sample));
      }
```

Comment: using `every` is the best solution. i especially like it because it'll stop the iteration as soon as it finds a falsy value (according to the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#description)

Comment: How to use it for 2D arrays?

Answer (score 10):

Shortest answer using underscore/lodash

```
function elementsEqual(arr) {
    return !_.without(arr, arr[0]).length
}
```

spec:

```
elementsEqual(null) // throws error
elementsEqual([]) // true
elementsEqual({}) // true
elementsEqual([1]) // true
elementsEqual([1,2]) // false
elementsEqual(NaN) // true
```

*edit:*

Or even shorter, inspired by Tom's answer:

```
function elementsEqual2(arr) {
    return _.uniq(arr).length <= 1;
}
```

spec:

```
elementsEqual2(null) // true (beware, it's different than above)
elementsEqual2([]) // true
elementsEqual2({}) // true
elementsEqual2([1]) // true
elementsEqual2([1,2]) // false
elementsEqual2(NaN) // true
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're already using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), then here's another option using `_.uniq`:

```
function allEqual(arr) {
    return _.uniq(arr).length === 1;
}
```

`_.uniq` returns a duplicate-free version of the array. If all the values are the same, then the length will be 1.

As mentioned in the comments, given that you may expect an empty array to return `true`, then you should also check for that case:

```
function allEqual(arr) {
    return arr.length === 0 || _.uniq(arr).length === 1;
}
```

Comment: But if array is empty, your answer will return `false`. While I think it should be `true`. Changing to `.length <= 1` shall be enough though.

Comment: @Kasztan that's a fair point. I've updated my answer to cover that case.

Answer (score 8):

every() function check if all elements of an array

```
    const checkArr = a => a.every( val => val === a[0] )
    checkArr(['a','a','a'])  // true
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Array.every` if supported:

```
var equals = array.every(function(value, index, array){
    return value === array[0];
});
```

Alternatives approach of a loop could be something like `sort`

```
var temp = array.slice(0).sort();
var equals = temp[0] === temp[temp.length - 1];
```

Or, if the items are like the question, something dirty like:

```
var equals = array.join('').split(array[0]).join('').length === 0;
```

Also works.

Comment: You have the first example backwards.  Should be `equals = !array.some( (v,i,a) => v!==a[0] )`.  Otherwise you're just checking that any value equals the first which will, of course, always be true :)

Comment: Not exactly, I used `some` instead of `every` as I mentioned in the first paragraph. :) Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 6):

**Yes,** you can check it also using filter as below, very simple, checking every values are the same as the first one:

```
//ES6
function sameValues(arr) {
  return arr.filter((v,i,a)=>v===a[0]).length === arr.length;
}
```

also can be done using every method on the array:

```
//ES6
function sameValues(arr) {
  return arr.every((v,i,a)=>v===a[0]);
}
```

and you can check your arrays like below:

```
sameValues(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']); // true
sameValues(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']); // false
```

Or you can add it to native Array functionalities in JavaScript if you reuse it a lot:

```
//ES6
Array.prototype.sameValues = Array.prototype.sameValues || function(){
 this.every((v,i,a)=>v===a[0]);
}
```

and you can check your arrays like below:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'].sameValues(); // true
['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'].sameValues(); // false
```

Answer (score 6):

Now you can make use of sets to do that easily.

```js
let a= ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']; // true
let b =['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'];// false

console.log(new Set(a).size === 1);
console.log(new Set(b).size === 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get this one-liner to do what you want using [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is), and ES6 arrow functions:

```
const all = arr => arr.every(x => Object.is(arr[0], x));
```

Comment: Please, describe the solution you're proposing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest way to do this is to create a loop to compare the each value to the next.  As long as there is a break in the "chain" then it would return false.  If the first is equal to the second, the second equal to the third and so on, then we can conclude that all elements of the array are equal to each other.

given an array data[], then you can use:

```
for(x=0;x<data.length - 1;x++){
    if (data[x] != data[x+1]){
        isEqual = false;            
    }
}
alert("All elements are equal is " + isEqual);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert array to a Set and check its size

In case of primitive array entries, i.e. `number`, `string`:

```js
const isArrayWithEqualEntries = array => new Set(array).size === 1
```

In case of array of objects with some field to be tested for equivalence, say `id`:

```js
const mapper = ({id}) => id
const isArrayWithEqualEntries = array => new Set(array.map(mapper)).size === 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
function same(a) {
    if (!a.length) return true;
    return !a.filter(function (e) {
        return e !== a[0];
    }).length;
}
```

The function first checks whether the array is empty. If it is it's values are equals..
Otherwise it filter the array and takes all elements which are different from the first one. If there are no such values => the array contains only equal elements otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.length && arr.reduce(function(a, b){return (a === b)?a:false;}) === arr[0];
```

Comment: Fails if the first item is `false`, i.e. `[false,true] => true`

Answer (score 2):

Its Simple.
Create a function and pass a parameter.
In that function copy the first index into a new variable.
Then Create a for loop and loop through the array.
Inside a loop create an while loop with a condition checking whether the new created variable is equal to all the elements in the loop.
if its equal return true after the for loop completes else return false inside the while loop.

```
function isUniform(arra){
    var k=arra[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
        while(k!==arra[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35568895/4793643) worked great but I wanted to add a tiny bit. It didn't work for me to use `===` because I was comparing arrays of arrays of objects, however throughout my app I've been using the [fast-deep-equal](https://github.com/epoberezkin/fast-deep-equal) package which I highly recommend. With that, my code looks like this:

```
let areAllEqual = arrs.every((val, i, arr) => equal(val, arr[0]) );
```

and my data looks like this:

```
[  
  [
    {
      "ID": 28,
      "AuthorID": 121,
      "VisitTypeID": 2
    },
    {
      "ID": 115,
      "AuthorID": 121,
      "VisitTypeID": 1
    },
    {
      "ID": 121,
      "AuthorID": 121,
      "VisitTypeID": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "ID": 121,
      "AuthorID": 121,
      "VisitTypeID": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "ID": 5,
      "AuthorID": 121,
      "VisitTypeID": 1
    },
    {
      "ID": 121,
      "AuthorID": 121,
      "VisitTypeID": 1
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop:

```
function isEqual(arr) {
  var first = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (first !== arr[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscore's `_.isEqual(object, other)` function seems to work well for arrays.  The order of items in the array matter when it checks for equality.  See http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual.

Answer (score 1):

```
var listTrue = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];
var listFalse = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'ab'];

function areWeTheSame(list) { 
    var sample = list[0];
    return !(list.some(function(item) {
        return !(item == sample);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Please also explain what you did instead of just pasting some code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isUniform(array) {   
  for (var i=1; i< array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] !== array[0]) { return false; }
  }

  for (var i=1; i< array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === array[0]) { return true; }
  }
}
```

- For the first loop; whenever it detects uneven, returns "false"
- The first loop runs, and if it returns false, we have "false"
- When it's not return false, it means there will be true, so we do the second loop. And of course we will have "true" from the second loop (because the first loop found it's NOT false)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a string by joining the array.
2. Create string by repetition of the first character of the given array
3. match both strings

```js
 function checkArray(array){
  return array.join("") == array[0].repeat(array.length); 
 }

 console.log('array: [a,a,a,a]: ' + checkArray(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']));
 console.log('array: [a,a,b,a]: ' + checkArray(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']));
```

And you are DONE !

Comment: I use this to compare whether two arrays have the same elements in the same order and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way when you use ES6 arrow function syntax:

```
x = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
!x.filter(e=>e!==x[0])[0]  // true

x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']
!x.filter(e=>e!==x[0])[0] // false

x = []
!x.filter(e=>e!==x[0])[0]  // true
```

And when you don't want to reuse the variable for array (x):

```
!['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'].filter((e,i,a)=>e!==a[0])[0]    // true
```

IMO previous poster who used array.every(...) has the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

this might work , you can use the comment out code as well that also woks well with the given scenerio.

```js
function isUniform(){
 var arrayToMatch = [1,1,1,1,1];
 var temp = arrayToMatch[0];
 console.log(temp);
  /* return arrayToMatch.every(function(check){
    return check == temp;
   });*/
var bool;
   arrayToMatch.forEach(function(check){
    bool=(check == temp);
   })
  console.log(bool);
}
isUniform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use index of operator for every item of array
to check if it exists or not. If even one item returns -1 (doesn't exist then it will be false)

```
const arr1 = [1, 3, 5];
const arr2 = [5, 7, 9];
const arr3 = [1, 3, 5];

arr1.every(item => arr2.indexOf(item) != -1)
// this will return false

arr1.every(item => arr3.indexOf(item) != -1)
// this will return true
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple one line solution, just compare it to an array filled with the first entry.

```
if(arr.join('') === Array(arr.length).fill(arr[0]).join(''))
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like a solution that can be used anywhere

Comment: It's pretty close to ok. Better would be something like:

   function arrayOfSame(arr) {
      return (arr.join('') == (new Array(arr.length+1).join(arr[0])));
   }

Answer (score -1):

```
**// Logical Solution:- Declare global array and one variable(To check the condition) whether all element of an array contains same value or not.**

    var arr =[];
    var isMatching = false;

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(String(arr[i]).toLowerCase()== "Your string to check"){
                isMatching=true;
                // Array has same value in all index of an array
            }
            else{
                isMatching=false;
                // Array Doesn't has same value in all index of an array
                break;
            }
        }
    // **Check isMatching variable is true or false**

        if(isMatching){ // True
            //If Array has same value in all index, then this block will get executed
        }
        else{ //False
            //If Array doesn't has same value in all index, then this block will get executed
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could count the number of distinct values in the array, if this value is 1 all the entries are the same.

Example:

```
array = np.array([1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
set(array) # this gives the different values present in the array (1,2,3)
len(set(array)) # this returns 3, 3 different values in the array
```

Answer (score -2):

another cool solution i like is using XOR operator :

```
console.log([5,5,5,5].reduce((a,b)=>a^b) == 0)
>> true
console.log([5,5,5,4].reduce((a,b)=>a^b) == 0)
>> false
```

Comment: This will only work when the number of items in the array are 2^n 
for eg 2,4,8 .....
values like 5,6,7 won't work

Comment: paste this in any IDE 
console.log([5,5,5,5,5].reduce((a,b)=>a^b) == 0)

Comment: yup that's right my bad

Answer (score -5):

In PHP, there is a solution very simple, one line method :

(count(array_count_values($array)) == 1)

For example :

```
$arr1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'];
$arr2 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'];


print (count(array_count_values($arr1)) == 1 ? "identical" : "not identical"); // identical
print (count(array_count_values($arr2)) == 1 ? "identical" : "not identical"); // not identical
```

That's all.

Comment: This is a JavaScript question - a PHP solution is not helpful.