# validation in if textbox having same values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform this action like if user choose same value for two different box i have to show some errors.my textbox code as follows.

```
<input class="order form-control vnumber" type="text" maxlength="1" name="Orderbox[]" required="true">
<input class="order form-control vnumber" type="text" maxlength="1" name="Orderbox[]" required="true">
<input class="order form-control vnumber" type="text" maxlength="1" name="Orderbox[]" required="true">
<input class="order form-control vnumber" type="text" maxlength="1" name="Orderbox[]" required="true">
```

so the textbox values should be different like 1,2,3,4 it should not be 1,1,1,1 so i have tried real time update using jquery.

```
$('.order').keyup(function () {       
    // initialize the sum (total price) to zero
    var val = 0;
    var next_val=0;
    // we use jQuery each() to loop through all the textbox with 'price' class
    // and compute the sum for each loop
    $('.order').each(function() {
        val+=$(this).val();
    });
      alert(val);
      if (next_val==val) {
    alert("same value");
      }
      next_val=val;
});
```

But its not working as i expected can anybody tell is there any solutions for this.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

JFIDDLE:
[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phZaL/)

Comment: you havent included jquery in your fiddle

Comment: Also your input tags aren't closed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/phZaL/6/ updated

Answer (score 2):

Try this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phZaL/7/)**.

```
var valarr = [];
$('.order').keyup(function () {

      var curr = $(this).val();
      if (jQuery.inArray(curr, valarr) > -1) {
          alert('exists');
      } else {
          valarr.push(curr);
      }

});
```

You can use **[arrays](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/)** to maintain values. To check the existence of value use **[inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to put more of the code inside the `.each()` loop. Also, change `val+=` to just `val=`

```
 $('.order').each(function() {
    val=$(this).val();
    alert(val);
    if (next_val==val) {
          alert("same value");
    }
    next_val=val;
 });
```

And keep in mind `next_val` is actually the previous value...

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/phZaL/8/

Answer (score 0):

***This will only work if all values entered till now have the same value***
*jQuery Code*

```
var arr = [];
$('.order').change(function () {
    arr.push($(this).val());
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        if (arr.AllValuesSame()) alert("Values are same");
    }
    var val = 0;
    $.each(arr, function () {
        val = parseInt(val) + parseInt(this);
    });
    $('.val').text(val);
});
Array.prototype.AllValuesSame = function () {
    if (this.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] !== this[0]) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

### [*Demo Fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/phZaL/9/)

> Made with great help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14832662/2260614) by @Robert