# Check if all elements in array are the same value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to check (**with jQuery**) if all 'li' in a list has style="display: none", 
but I'm a little lost.

```
<ul class="thumbs">
  <li style="display: none;">Element 1</li>
  <li style="display: none;">Element 2</li>
  <li style="display: none;">Element 3</li>
  <li style="display: none;">Element 4</li>
  <li style="display: none;">Element 5</li>
</ul>

var $el = $('.thumbs li');
var elStyle = $el.map(function() {
   return $(this).attr('style');
});

console.log(elStyle);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r2rwe2nw/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if all values of array are equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832603/check-if-all-values-of-array-are-equal)

Comment: Simply check the count of visible element  `$('.thumbs li:visible').length == 0`

Comment: @PranavCBalan There are so many things in my head that did not remember the obvious ... haha . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `map`, try [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ing the list elements based on their CSS properties and checking the length of the resulting array:

```js
var visibleElements = $('.thumbs li').filter(function(item) {
  return this.style.display !== 'none';
});

console.log(visibleElements.length > 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="thumbs">
  <li style="display: none;">Element 1</li>
  <li style="display: none;">Element 2</li>
  <li style="display: none;">Element 3</li>
  <li style="display: none;">Element 4</li>
  <li style="display: none;">Element 5</li>
</ul>
```