# How to check the values of an array full of Jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I am making a tic-tac-toe game for fun and I am trying to do something a little different.

I am currently trying to check winning combinations by iterating through an array of stored tds that were grabbed with Jquery.

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS = [$("#square_0, #square_1, #square_2"), 
$("#square_6, #square_7, #square_8"),
$("#square_0, #square_3, #square_6"), 
$("#square_3, #square_4, #square_5"), 
$("#square_1, #square_4, #square_7"),
$("#square_2, #square_5, #square_8"), 
$("#square_0, #square_4, #square_8"), $("#square_6, #square_4, #square_2")]
```

So, basically, WIN_COMBINATIONS[0] is a winning combo.  What is the best way to iterate through, and actually check the .html of the Jquery object?

Basically, I would like to do something like this

```
if (WIN_COMBINATIONS[0].html = "X", "X", "X") {
        //do something here
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The X might belong to different players

Comment: Well, there are only two players, and if all the spots are filled with an "X", the game will stop and declare a winner.  That is what I am after.  Just a simple game of tic tac toe :D

Comment: you will need to do a "Deep Equals" of each item in the array... Looking now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WIN_COMBINATIONS.forEach(function(combination){
    if(combination.map(function(){return $(this).text()}).toArray().join("") == "XXX") { 
        console.log("winning combination")   
    } 
})
```

Comment: Brilliant Answer!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks Juvian

Answer (score 0):

if ES6 (ES2015) is OK than you can try [reduce to find match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832603/check-if-all-values-of-array-are-equal#21266395)

`!!array.reduce(function(a, b){ return (a === b) ? a : NaN; });`

Results:

```
var array = ["a", "a", "a"] => result: "true"
var array = ["a", "b", "a"] => result: "false"
var array = ["false", ""] => result: "false"
var array = ["false", false] => result: "false"
var array = ["false", "false"] => result: "true"
var array = [NaN, NaN] => result: "false"
```

Warning:
`var array = [] => result: TypeError thrown`

All credit to:
[Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit)