# do something if all images have the same width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something if all `.cimg` have the same width.

```
<img class='cimg' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='cimg' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='cimg' src='...' alt='img'>
```

**js**

```
let w = $.map($('.cimg'), (e) => $(e)[0].naturalWidth);
```

result - `[960, 960, 960]`

```
if(all elements of w are equal){do_something();}  // how to do this?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all values of array are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832603/check-if-all-values-of-array-are-equal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

You can use `[...new Set()]` to get all the unique items from the array, then simply check the `length` of the resulted array. If the length is `1` then all width are same otherwise not:

```js
let w = $.map($('.cimg'), (e) => $(e)[0].naturalWidth); 
w = [...new Set(w)]
if(w.length == 1){console.log('same');}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='cimg' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='cimg' src='...' alt='img'>
<img class='cimg' src='...' alt='img'>
```

Comment: any link for `[...new Set()]` pls