# Chai - Assert that all elements in the array are equal to a given value with

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, chai

I have this array of strings:

```
[ "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", ]
```

Is it possible to make an assertion with Chai that all elements in the array are equal to the certain value?

```
arrayFromApiResponse = [ "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", ]
expectedFruit = "apple"

expect(arrayFromApiResponse).to ???
```

I need to test that each value in the `arrayFromApiResponse` is `"apple"`

I found this https://github.com/chaijs/Chai-Things

Seems like with this library it can be accomplished like this:

```
expect(arrayFromApiResponse).should.all.be.a(expectedFruit)
```

But is it possible to achieve this without additional library? Maybe I can make some changes to `arrayFromApiResponse` so it can be validated by Chai?

**UPD:**
I have updated the question title to prevent marking my question as duplicate with reference to this type of questions:
[Check if all values of array are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832603/check-if-all-values-of-array-are-equal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all values of array are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832603/check-if-all-values-of-array-are-equal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method.

```js
const arrayFromApiResponse = [ "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", ]
const expectedFruit = "apple"

const allAreExpectedFruit = arrayFromApiResponse.every(x => x === expectedFruit);

console.log(allAreExpectedFruit);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arrayFromApiResponse = [ "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple"]
const expectedFruit = "apple"
```

You can do this with `filter()` but the most efficient would be a good old `for` loop:

```js
function test(arr, val){
  for(let i=0; i<arrayFromApiResponse.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] !== val) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

The reason this is more efficient is that this function will terminate as soon as it sees a value which doesn't equal the expected value. Other functions will traverse the entire array, which can be extremely inefficient. Use it like this:

```js
expect(test(arrayFromApiResponse, expectedFruit)).toBe(true);
```

Comment: [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) works exactly the same, it returns false as soon as it has found an element that returns false. This can be found under "Description".