# How to combine multiple "equal to"'s in javaScript if condition?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, compare

If got a number of values which I want to compare (they all have to be the same).
The function `e(row,col)` returns an attribute of an element in a grid.

Is it possible to write something like…

```js
if(e(1,2)==e(2,2)==e(3,2)==e(4,2)){...}
```

…instead of …

```js
if(e(1,2)==e(2,2)&&e(2,2)==e(3,2)&&e(3,2)==e(4,2)){…}
```

?

Comment: [Check if all values of array are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14832603)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make an array of parameters to pass to the function, then get the result of the first call, then check that `.every` one of the other array pairs are equal to the first:

```
const params = [
  [1, 2],
  [2, 2],
  [3, 2],
  [4, 2],
];
const res = e(...params[0]);
if (params.slice(1).every(args => e(...args) === res)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Or use a loop, if the indicies are this predictable:

```
const res = e(1, 2);
let allMatch = true;
for (let i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
  if (e(1, i) !== res) {
    allMatch = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (allMatch) {
  // do stuff
}
```