# Check if RGB colours are the same

Tags: colors, ecmascript-5, photoshop-script

I'm trying to see if colours are the same in Photoshop scripting

```
RGB 0,128,60 == RGB 0,128,60 // true
RGB 0,128,60 == RGB 0,128,64 // false
```

Only most fancy javascript bits like `every` and `=>` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832603/check-if-all-values-of-array-are-equal) don't work with Photoshop's ECMA script

This is what I have (based on [Dogbert's example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646943/check-if-each-item-in-an-array-is-identical-in-javascript)), but I'm sure there's got to be a cleaner way. Apart from converting them to hex and then comparing them.

```
alert(identical_colours([[0,128,60], [0,128,60]])); // true
alert(identical_colours([[0,128,60], [0,128,64]])); // false



function identical_colours(arr)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
  {
    if(arr[i][0] !== arr[i+1][0])
    {
      return false;
    }
    if(arr[i][1] !== arr[i+1][1])
    {
      return false;
    }
    if(arr[i][2] !== arr[i+1][2])
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // True! Yay!
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Photoshop own color definition — `SolidColor` — that has a `.isEqual()` method:

```js
var color1 = colorFromRGB(0, 128, 60);

var color2 = colorFromRGB(0, 128, 60);

alert(color1.isEqual(color2)); // > true

function colorFromRGB(r, g, b)
{
  var color = new SolidColor();
  color.rgb.red = r;
  color.rgb.green = g;
  color.rgb.blue = b;
  return color;
}
```

Comment: I knew about SolidColor, it's difficult not to create a colour without it :), but I would have never have guessed at .isEqual() method!

Comment: @GhoulFool I just made myself a warper that generates `SolidColor` from different inputs. Similar to my answer but from an object as argument: `newSolidColor({type:'rgb',value:[0,0,0]})`, `newSolidColor({type:'hex',value:'ffffff'})`, etc